# How/where to create a shared method out of jquery/erb code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coding-style, erb

In my rails 3.1 app I've added update.js.erb, create.js.erb, and destroy.js.erb templates to handle javascript requests, and everything is working great. These each have similar chunks of code that need to be called to update portions of the DOM.

```
...

// recalculate envelope total
$('#<%= "#{dom_id @transaction.envelope} .available" %>').html('<%= "#{formatted_money @transaction.envelope.amount_available}" %>');
```

I want to encapsulate this logic, what is The Rails Way to make this more "DRY"?

What I imagine is something like this:

```
<%= recalculate_envelope(@transaction.envelope) %>
```

But I don't know where this method should go so that it is shared to each of the templates, and potentially other templates for different controllers. For that matter, what it should even return?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the method in a helper class. If you want the method to be available to all vews (no matter which controller) you must put it in the class `ApplicationHelper`. For the views of a specific controller in the specifiic helper class (e.g. `ProfileHelper` to make the method visibile for all views of a `ProfileController`).

So in your helper class you can implement your method, e.g.:

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def recalculate_envelope(dom_id, envelope)
    "$('##{dom_id envelope} .available').html('#{formatted_money envelope.amount_available}');"
  end
end
```

And then you can access your method in your views with

```
<%= recalculate_envelope(@transaction.envelope) %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was as simple as that, but I guess that's how helpers for HTML templates work so why not for the js too?